# Control A on Mac Terminal behaves unexpectedly while using python ipdb

Tags: macos, terminal, python, ipython

When I'm using Python ipdb (and this only happens on one of my three macs), I type Ctrl-A to get to the beginning of the line (after running a few statements without issue). The cursor APPEARS to jump back to character 5, 6, or so (it's not consistent), and if I type, the text APPEARS to originate at the cursor, but actually, the text is being added to the beginning of the line. Visually it's entirely confusing. If I left-arrow back to the beginning of the line (which is slow and annoying), I don't notice the issue.

Here are some screenshots to help illustrate the problem:

[image]

As illustrated below, the "abc" appears to be going in where the cursor is, but actually it's going in before "print", hence the syntax error

[image]

Any ideas for what's wrong or how to troubleshoot?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Destroying and re-installing the virtualenv I was using appears to have solved this problem.